# How can I set `parallel=True` in numba while I use np.power()?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, jit, numba

I'm going to boost my code using numba. However, power function in the parallel mode does not work well i.e. for the function below:

```
import numpy as np
import numba

@numba.njit(parallel=True, fastmath = True)
def decay_rate(mV, mp):
    drate=(np.power(mp,-3))
    return drate
```

It says:

> The keyword argument 'parallel=True' was specified but no transformation for parallel execution was possible.

The function is more complex than what is demonstrated above (numba overhead worth it!). Also, I've tried the `**` for the power before but the result is the same.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Just a question: Is your `mp` an array? Could you add an sample call to the question, e.g. `decay_rate(..., np.array([2.0,3,4,5,6])`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The message simply states that you specified `parallel` but there was nothing found to be parallelized. That's because `np.power` (the same applies to the array-power operator `**`) is a function defined somewhere else - and you cannot parallelize a function you're calling. However you can parallelize functions you're writing or call functions in parallel.

If you want to compute the power in parallel, you could do so using `numba.prange` (see also [Explicit Parallel Loops (numba documentation)](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/parallel.html#explicit-parallel-loops)):

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

@nb.njit(parallel=True, fastmath=True)
def decay_rate(mp):
    drate = np.empty(mp.size)
    for idx in nb.prange(mp.size):
        drate[idx] = np.power(mp[idx], -3)
    return drate
```

The `prange` explicitly tells numba to parallelize the loop.